# Created a website. Now I've no idea how to get rid of it

Tags: sharepoint-online

Sorry for that horrible title. Basically I've created a new site using the "Create site" link on the SharePoint O365 page but now I can't seem to get rid of it! It says I'm following that site etc.

I have full control over that site but there still isn't an option to delete it in the site settings. When I go to Sites and Workspaces it just says I've got no sites. Can I just unfollow the site and forget about it? It doesn't seem as the most elegant solution.

Sorry for such a basic question but I'm really lost...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a modern site? If so, you would have to delete the associated group in the the admin center under groups -> groups. The group has the same name as the site. It could take a while until the site is actually deleted.

I cannot imagine a more retarded way to implement site deletion, but oh well...

Comment: That is... wow. Is there some kind of documentation on this kind of stuff? Thank you nonetheless!

Answer (score 0):

Under **Site Settings > Site Actions** there should be the possibility **Delete this site**. In case you don't see it there, it's probably a permission issue.